# Linq2SQL related records

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

I'm sure this has been answered but I can't find it.

Say I have three tables;

Projects

- Id <= unique key
- name

Attributes

- Id <= unique key
- Name

ProjectAttributes

- id <= unique key
- ProjectId
- AttributeId

I'm using a dbml file and I have all the associations drawn up within the dbml.

So how in my view, do I itterate through all the Attributes for the project.

I thought;

```
<% foreach (Project project in Model){%>
    <% foreach (Repository.Attribute attr in project.ProjectAttributes ) { %>
```

but that clearly doesn't work.

So how, given a project, do I get all the attributes associated to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many to many associations in L2S are always done including the foreign key table, so it should probably be:

```
<% foreach (Project project in Model){%>
    <% foreach (ProjectAttribute attr in project.ProjectAttributes ) { %>
```

And `attr.Attribute` will then be your needed attribute

Comment: It didn't help much that I had the association the wrong way around from Attributes to ProjectAttributes.

Your answer pointed me to that mismatch thank you.